# Changing how windows displays using Win API?

Tags: winapi

While I have some experience with the WinAPI I do not have a ton, so I have a question for people who do have much experience in it.  My question concerns what the limit of our power is.  Can we change how windows fundamentally displays?

For example, can I cause windows to render a screen size bigger than the display and pan across it, kind of like workspaces but without separation?  Can I apply distortion to the top and bottom of the screen?  If distortion is not possible can I have an application mirror what windows is displaying with very little delay?

The biggest question I have is the first one, because if I can make windows render virtual workspaces and pan seamlessly between them then I figure it is possible to make a separate application which handles the distortion on a mirrored image of the desktop.  Again, apologies for the vague questions, but I really want to know if we are able to do this stuff, at least in theory, before I dive deep into learning more on the API.  If the WinAPI does not allow it is there another way to do this kind of stuff in Windows?

EDIT: Some clarification. What I want to do is basically extend the desktop to a very large size (not sure on exact size yet), both vertically and horizontally.  Section the large desktop into workspaces of a specific size which can seamlessly be transitioned across and windows moved across.  It would transition workspaces based on a head tracking device and/or mouse movement.  Note that when I say workspaces this could be achieved by zomming in and then panning the zoom as well. I also need to be able to distort the screen, such as curving the edges, and render the screen twice.  That is the bare minimum of what I am wanting to do.

Comment: This is the stackoverflow section of stackexchange. It's precisely geared to programming questions. However, your question is quite general and difficult to answer.  Do you want to take over the screen and display your own content without Windows getting in the way?  No problem.  Or do you want to display the normal Windows desktop and control it?  That's far more complex.  So your question would benefit from being more specific.

Comment: Edited post with specific examples of what I am trying to do.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: So I take it that you want to display the normal Windows desktop rather than your own content, but you want to be able to control how it's displayed?  Is that right?

Comment: I'll be very interested to see if anyone has an answer because I don't think there's a way to do that.  Explorer.exe paints and controls the desktop and to my knowledge offers no API to override it, but I could be wrong.  It is possible to *replace* explorer.exe, however, but it would be a huge chunk of work.

Comment: Could always do nasty things such as detecting the shell and then injecting into it to take over how it draws the desktop.

Comment: Sound a little bit like multiple desktops, like kde for example, offers it. Hmmm, one always can hook several window-procedure calls via hooking, for example , here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1037/Hooks-and-DLLs

http://securityxploded.com/dll-injection-and-hooking.php

AFAIK, there are many possibilities, which can be realized with hooks, but if Your required demands all will be possible, You mostly must check Yourself.
The desktop window is also nothing more than a window with its callback and so on.

You should try to hook its callback and play around with changing the WM_PAINT

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The most feasible way I come up with is using a virtual graphics driver (like what `Windows Remote Desktop` does, which creates a virtual graphics card and a virtual display). Sadly you will lose the ability to run some programs needing advanced graphics API (such as 3D games, 3D modelling tools or so).

There're some examples:

http://virtualmonitor.github.io/

https://superuser.com/questions/62051/is-there-a-way-to-fake-a-dual-second-monitor

And remember Windows has a limit on display resolution (for each and for altogether). I don't remember the exact number but it should be less than 32768*32768.